# Lost links in Joomla 4 breadcrumbs

Tags: navigation, breadcrumbs, joomla4

I seem to have lost the links within breadcrumbs on a couple of my Joomla 4 sites.

[image]

Any idea how I can recover the links??

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you don't have a "How To" menu item (or it's just a separator), then the breadcrumbs link can't point to anything.

Comment: There is a How To menu - both sides.  One site is an 'improvement' on the other! Or should be. I must have missed something somewhere - but thanks - I will look at the menus and see if i can find a difference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).